# Blue notification that new questions match filter

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, design

Previously for filters, new questions showed up as a small, unicolored red dot. Now, it appears they are a light blue with some darker border around them (not sure exactly how to describe it)

[image: Blue notification for filter]

Are other people seeing it like this (or is it a weird bug on my end)? And does anyone know the reason for the change, if it was changed intentionally?

I know that it's possible to create a user script/custom CSS to revert this change for my experience, but I'm probably not going to.

Comment: Yeah, can confirm, it's not just you. Related on MSE: [Misaligned dot next to unread custom question filters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/372468)

Comment: This isn’t new. See [What does the blue dot in front of the review queues mean?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/369177/289905).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We switched this activity indicator to our [shared Stacks component](https://stackoverflow.design/product/components/activity-indicator/). This is not a bug, but alignment could be improved, especially on Windows.